# Override HTTP method with Play framework

Tags: java, http, rest, playframework, playframework-1.x

Some web frameworks offer the possibility to "override" the HTTP method with a hidden form field:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" type="_method" value="PUT">
  ...
</form>
```

Is it possible to override the HTTP method with the [Play](http://www.playframework.org) framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: This is for Play 1.x only.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java) for the `Router.route()` method, it uses the `x-http-method-override` parameter in the query string. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/play/+bug/538870) you should also be able to achieve this using HTTP Headers, but I couldn't see this in the source code.

To get it to work, you need to add the override to the request string. I ran the following example to get it to work.

```
<form action="@{Application.form}?x-http-method-override=PUT" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" type="go" value="go">
</form>
```

If you set the logging level to TRACE, you will see the following output, showing the method has changed. You should see an output like --

```
08:20:34,855 TRACE ~ init: begin
08:20:34,858 TRACE ~ Route: /application/form - x-http-method-override=PUT
08:20:34,859 TRACE ~ request method POST overriden to PUT
08:20:34,860 TRACE ~ ------- public static void controllers.Application.form()
08:20:34,861 TRACE ~ init: end true
```

You can also check the `request.method` in your controller to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

In Play2, this is not possible and the creators [have indicated](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2063) that there is no plan to support it. You'll have to manually intercept the request and change the HTTP method by overriding `Global.onRouteRequest`.